# Installing SQL Server ODBC library throwing error in Azure databricks runtime 8.3

Tags: python, sql-server, pyodbc, azure-databricks

I am trying to install ODBC library for SQL Server 2017 to be used to connect to SQL Server using pyodbc Python package. I got this piece of code from StackOverflow only. I am getting error while installing.

This is the script I am running:

```
%sh
curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | apt-key add -
curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/16.04/prod.list > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-release.list
sudo apt-get update
sudo ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get -q -y install msodbcsql17
```

And I get this error:

```
% Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed

  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0Warning: apt-key output should not be parsed (stdout is not a terminal)
E: This command can only be used by root.

100   983  100   983    0     0   3640      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  3640
**(23) Failed writing body**
/bin/bash: line 1: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-release.list: Permission denied
sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified
sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified
```

I tried another script as below.

```
%sh
curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | apt-key add -
curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/16.04/prod.list > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-release.list 
apt-get update
ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get install msodbcsql17
apt-get -y install unixodbc-dev
sudo apt-get install python3-pip -y
pip3 install --upgrade pyodbc
```

This one also failing as below.

```
 % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed

  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0Warning: apt-key output should not be parsed (stdout is not a terminal)
E: This command can only be used by root.

  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
100   983  100   983    0     0   1790      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  1787
(23) Failed writing body
/bin/bash: line 1: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-release.list: Permission denied
Reading package lists...
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/apt/lists/lock - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to lock directory /var/lib/apt/lists/
**E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to acquire the dpkg frontend lock (/var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend), are you root?
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to acquire the dpkg frontend lock (/var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend), are you root?**
sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Collecting pyodbc
  Downloading pyodbc-4.0.32.tar.gz (280 kB)
Building wheels for collected packages: pyodbc
  Building wheel for pyodbc (setup.py): started
  Building wheel for pyodbc (setup.py): finished with status 'done'
  Created wheel for pyodbc: filename=pyodbc-4.0.32-cp38-cp38-linux_x86_64.whl size=317312 sha256=baca7539ec5fb88f940fb9ba944609c211a1c84d73d02f659c9deaa0f463b700
  Stored in directory: /home/spark-fcbd5404-644a-45c3-a4b1-9a/.cache/pip/wheels/68/de/de/65a129482924e96fb701c51488b907953acf25fe623bb177b3
Successfully built pyodbc
Installing collected packages: pyodbc
Successfully installed pyodbc-4.0.32
WARNING: You are using pip version 20.2.4; however, version 21.2.4 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the '/databricks/python3/bin/python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

Not sure how to install SQL Server ODBC and pyodbc properly. Please help.

Comment: The prod.list URL that you're referencing, and perhaps some of the other commands, are specific to Ubuntu 16.04. What distribution is your Az Databricks cluster using?

Comment: Try using `uname -a` or `lsb_release -a` or `cat /etc/os-release` to determine which distribution and specific version you're dealing with and then follow the appropriate instructions from [Install the Microsoft ODBC driver for SQL Server (Linux)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/installing-the-microsoft-odbc-driver-for-sql-server).

Comment: Checked the OS version. it is NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="18.04.5 LTS (Bionic Beaver)" . Executed below command as mentioned in the Microsoft article. But getting below error,  sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified
  --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0Warning: apt-key output should not be parsed (stdout is not a terminal)
E: This command can only be used by root.

100   983  100   983    0     0  11430      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 11430
/bin/bash: line 2: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-release.list: Permission denied

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you to restart the cluster and try to run the command again.

I had tested on the Databricks Runtime: 8.3 (includes Apache Spark 3.1.1, Scala 2.12).

```
 %sh
 curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | apt-key add -
 curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/16.04/prod.list > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-release.list 
 apt-get update
 ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get install msodbcsql17
```

Successfully install ODBC SQL 17 Driver on ADB 8.3.

[image]

Comment: I tried this but still getting the error.   
/bin/bash: line 1: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-release.list: Permission denied
Reading package lists...
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/apt/lists/lock - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to lock directory /var/lib/apt/lists/
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to acquire the dpkg frontend lock (/var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend), are you root?